# SlimPHP Route not being called

Tags: php, slim

I'm currently trying to understand why this route is not being hit

```
$app->group('/sites', function () use ($app) {
    $app->post('/add', function ($request, $response, $args) { 
        $data = $request->getParsedBody();
        return json_encode($data);
    });

    $app->post('/delete', function ($request, $response, $args) { 
        $data = $request->getParsedBody();
        return json_encode($data);
    });
});
```

In order for the call to not return a 404 error I have to register the following route globally.

```
$app->post('/', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $data = $request->getParsedBody();
    return json_encode($data);
});
```

If I try and register this as /sites/delete it throws an exception telling me I cannot register two of the same routes so the application knows that I have registered this route.

The code that calls this route is a simple jQuery $http method

```
$.post('/sites/delete', data);
```

I have checked to make sure I am actually sending data along with this POST request.

Everything in Chrome Dev Tools is telling me I am posting to the correct route, however for some reason SlimPHP appears to not be honoring this request properly, while all other routes in my application seem to work fine, minus this one /sites group. Am I doing something wrong in registering this group? I've registered other groups like this and they all appear to be working fine?

Comment: What do the webserver logs show?

Comment: Is it possible that you have `sites` directory in your web server root www directory? If so, most`.htaccess` rewrite codes will ignore the rewrite if an actual directory or file that matches the route exists, so you will not be passed to slim at all.

Comment: Ohh my f****** god damnit.....

Comment: Please submit that as a response so I can give you the credit of the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here ended up being that I had a sites directory. Per Ron Dandon's comment on the above post.

```
Most .htaccess rewrite codes will ignore the rewrite if an actual directory or file that matches the route exists, so you will not be passed to slim at all.
```